# How to get the path relative to the App_Data folder in asp.net without form

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net web application,I have to read somef file inside the App_Data folder,but I have no idea hot to set the path.

If in the web form,I know I can use the:

```
Sever.mapPath("~/App_Data");
```

But now I want to retrive the path in the .cs file in the App_code.

So there is no HttpServer context there.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp.net have System.IO namespace which contain  many functions related to files.

you can get both path and file related function in below namespace

```
System.IO.Path
System.IO.File
```

you can get full file path in .cs file as below

```
string strFullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/App_Code/Class1.cs"));
```

Hope this will helps you...

Comment: I'm not sure how this is the answer. hguser asked how to get the path when there is no Server object/property, but that's what you used in the answer. Simon Svensson's answer is correct: use HostingEnvironment instead of Server.

Answer (score 12):

Use [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx) instead.